# Non-exhaustive patterns

Tags: haskell, non-exhaustive-patterns

Given I have the following code:

```
data Note = C | Db | D | Eb | E | F | Gb | G | Ab | A | Bb | B
      deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum)

next :: Note -> Note
next B = C
next n = succ n

previous :: Note -> Note
previous C = B
previous n = pred n

resolveAscendingInterval :: Int -> Note -> Note
resolveAscendingInterval 0 note = note
resolveAscendingInterval interval note = resolveAscendingInterval (interval -1) (next note)

resolveDescendingInterval :: Int -> Note -> Note
resolveDescendingInterval 0 note = note
resolveDescendingIInterval interval note = resolveDescendingIInterval (interval -1) (previous note)

main :: IO ()
    main = do
    print $ resolveAscendingInterval 3 C
    print $ resolveDescendingInterval 3 C
```

resolveAscendingInterval works fine, but when I run resolveDescendingInterval I get:

**Non-exhaustive patterns in function resolveDescendingInterval**

Their code and logic are very similar, so I don't have a clue of whats wrong

Another thing: Is there another way to achieve this behavior without recursion?

Comment: You have a typo in the name of 'resolveDescendingInterval', so there is no generic case for that function.

Comment: omg sorry for the dumb question, FP complete VI's mode cursor is getting an aditional char on visual mode.

Comment: GHC should emit two warnings on the code above: about the non exhaustive function, and about the misnamed function lacking a type signature. Enable warnings if you did not -- they can be really useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a typo.  Notice `resolveDescendingIInterval` is a different function from `resolveDescendingInterval`.  Get rid of that extra `I`.

EDIT: Consider the following slightly unsafe code:

```
resolveDecendingInterval interval note = toEnum (fromEnum note - interval)
```

This is a partial function - it will fail when the interval is too large and we call `toEnum` on something out of range. You can clamp the range via code such as `max (fromEnum (minBound :: Note)) . min (fromEnum (maxBound :: Note))`. But there's probably a smarter way I'm just not thinking off immediately.

One alternative would be to clamp the `interval` via `rem interval (fromEnum note)` but then you'll need to handle the case when note is minBound separately.